# Direction of the static friction force at the center of a rotating disc?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If a particle were at the exact center of a rotating disc, what direction would the static friction be?

Answer (score 0):

If it were a point particle, there would be no static friction.

If it were a small circle, each part of the circle would need static friction acting inwards towards the middle of the disk, to provide the centripetal force.

Without any friction there would be a tendency for the particle to stretch and become a larger circle, with each part moving outwards to a larger radius.

The friction need not be large as the tension in the circle would also hold each part of the circle in.

Answer (score 0):

Friction *always* opposes the would-be motion if there were no friction. In this case, there is no motion at the center, and hence no friction.